# DSolve does not solve 2nd order linear PDE with variable coefficients

Tags: differential-equations

I find that DSolve can solve

`DSolve[x*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] - D[u[x, y], x, y] == 0, u, {x, y}]`

or

`DSolve[x*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] - x *D[u[x, y], x, y] == 0, u, {x, y}]`

or

`DSolve[x*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] - 3*D[u[x, y], x, y] == 0, u, {x, y}]}`

but cannot solve

`DSolve[x*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] - a *D[u[x, y], x, y] == 0, u, {x, y}]`

or

`DSolve[x*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] - y *D[u[x, y], x, y] == 0, u, {x, y}]`

Can I re-pose the equation to make it work?
thanks,
GB

MMa 10.3, 11.1

Comment: `DSolve[]'s` support for PDE equations is still somewhat limited,
 so don't be surprised if some things don't work yet.See **Results**:https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/maple_2019_and_mma_12/index.htm

Comment: You can break the last PDE down into two successive quadratures: `Fold[
 Function[{eq, var}, 
    DSolve[eq /. First[#1], var, {x, y}]] @@ #2 &, {{}}, 
 Transpose@{{x*D[v[x, y], {x}] - y*D[v[x, y], y] == 0, 
    D[u[x, y], x] == v[x, y]}, {v, u}}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, something comes out. Being thick between the ears, I have not been successful in backtesting. It is possible to do so?

Comment: @MichaelE2. Now it seems to check. Thanks for passing on this useful technique.

Answer (score 2):

Try some Assumptions on the first one.

```
$Assumptions = a > 0

DSolve[x*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] - a*D[u[x, y], x, y] == 0, u, {x, y}]
(*{{u -> Function[{x, y}, C[1][a*Log[x] + y]/E^(y/a) + C[2][y]]}}*)
```

Version 12.  The second one is still no go in automatic mode.  It is, however, separable and could be solved that way.

Comment: `Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals && a != 0` also works.